# Magento update index for selected products

Tags: magento

Is it possible to programmatically uptate indexes only for disered products?
Not for all products via

**"Admin->Configuration->Index Management"**

(because it freezes frontend for a long time).

I found `Mage::getSingleton('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex($productsIds)`.

But it raises error on nonexisting tables "catalogindex_...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Use the **"Update On Save"** re-indexing mode.

it will do re-index on the fly for that single product you have saved.

For more Details you can review official [Documentation link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing)

hope this will sure help you.